# How to see how tables are related with IBM System i Access for Windows?

Tags: database, ibm-midrange, db2-400, iseries-navigator

How to see how tables are related with IBM System i Access for Windows?
ID keys and so on.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the table definition from Access using the database tool in the iSeries Navigator.

If you are looking for a complete relational overview I recommend [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/) and the [jtopen](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/i-javatoolbox/) driver.

[image: DbVisualizer Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [dbvis.com](https://www.dbvis.com/images/mainwindow-win7.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Use the iSeries Navigator Database map feature:

[image]